# SQL Server Query for distinct rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I query for distinct customers?  Here's the table I have..

```
CustID  DATE    PRODUCT
=======================
1       Aug-31  Orange
1       Aug-31  Orange
3       Aug-31  Apple   
1       Sept-24 Apple
4       Sept-25 Orange
```

This is what I want.

```
# of New Customers            DATE
========================================
2                            Aug-31 
1                            Sept-25
```

Thanks!

Comment: `SELECT Date, COUNT(DISTINCT CustID) FROM YourTable GROUP BY Date`?

Comment: Why no customer on Sept 24 and one on Sept 25 in your desired result?

Comment: well Sept 24 is a returning customer.  So I don't care about repeat customers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bit tricky.  You want to count the *first* date a customer appears and then do the aggregation:

```
select mindate, count(*) as NumNew
from (select CustId, min(Date) as mindate
      from table t
      group by CustId
     ) c
group by mindate
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a simple common table expression to find the first time a user id is used;

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT date, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY custid ORDER BY date) rn
  FROM customers
)
SELECT COUNT(*)[# of New Customers], date FROM cte
WHERE rn=1
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bbe55/1).